# Convert string to list of UTF-8 code in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am getting a string from a postgres database by active record and I need to convert it to a list of UTF-8 codes.

The code that I fetch from database is a Persian character so it should look like an Arabic character.

```
def convertHex

  @user=DoctorProfile.where(id: params[:id])
  #  ar=@user.pluck(:first_name)
  ar=Array.new
  pri=Array.new
  ar=@user.pluck(:first_name)
  ar.split(",").map { |s| s.to_s }

  ar.each do |p|
    pri.push(p.ord.to_s + " , ")
  end

  # ar=@user.split("")
  #  ar = ar.each_byte.map { |b| b.to\_s(16) }.join
  #ar.each do |c|
  #    b=b +','+ c
  #end

  render json: pri  ,status:200
end
```

I get this

```
[
  "1590 , "
]
```

But I want something like this:

```
[
  "1590 , 2123 , 1112 , ..."
]
```

Comment: Hi Sandro.  This answer is a bit of a mess, but I think it can be improved.  (1) it needs proper indentation.  (2) 1590 isn't a valid ASCII code (ASCII values are seven or eight bits long), so I think you are probably looking for UTF codes, not ASCII codes, but the question should clarify this. (3) You can probably rewrite this question to be in pure Ruby, without Rails, by putting the conversion in a separate function.  Then you can show how the function is used, showing the actual input you are giving the function.

Comment: yes i need utf not ascii sorry

Comment: the 1590 is right it is a persian char but 2123,1112 are dummy, I spend two days on this case, i absolutely don't know what should i have to do with this case

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String#unpack()` method which [decodes str (which may contain binary data) according to the format string, returning an array of each value extracted](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-unpack):

```
# find will already return an object, not an array
# note it will throw an exception if user with id doesn't exist
# to get nil instead of exception, use find_by_id(params[:id])
@user = DoctorProfile.find(params[:id])

char_codes = @user.first_name.unpack('U*')
```

Or, if `first_name` may be `nil`, you can handle it with the *safe navigation operator*:

```
char_codes = @user.first_name&.unpack('U*') || []
```

Where `U` stands for UTF-8, and `*` will use up all remaining elements.

It will return an array of codes:

```
"Any Name".unpack('U*')
# => [65, 110, 121, 32, 78, 97, 109, 101]
```

And if you need a `String` of codes separated by commas (as in your example), you can simply `join` it:

```
char_codes.join(', ')
```